# Riemann removable singularity theorem for annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $\mathbb{D}^*=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ 0 < |z| < 1 \}$ denote the unit punctured disk in the complex plane. [Riemann's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) about removable singularities in particular implies the following:

If $f:\mathbb{D}^* \to \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded holomorphic function, then there exists a unique holomorphic extension $F: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ to the whole unit disk.

**Question** is it possible to get an analogous extension statement if we replace the punctured unit disk by a complex annulus $A(r,R)=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ r < |z| < R \}$? In this case "remove the singularity" should mean something like being at least continuous up to the [inner] boundary of the annulus, or maybe even holomorphic on some open neighborhood of it. More explicitly if $f:A(r,R)\to \mathbb{C}$ is bounded and holomorphic, is there some hope to get some continuous extension to $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ r \leq |z| < R \}$, or maybe some holomorphic extension to $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ r - \varepsilon < |z| < R \}$?

Comment: Since you can't have a holomorphic function on a non-open set, what you would really need to be able to do is extend the boundary beyond $|z|=r$ to some $|z|>r-\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, sorry if the question was not clear, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such hope. For a simple example, take $f(z)=1/z$.

In fact, an annulus is a domain of existence for $H^\infty$ as well as $A$, i.e. there exists bounded resp. continuous up to the boundary holomorphic functions on the annulus which can't be extended holomorphically across any boundary point.

More concretely, let $g$ be your favorite bounded/continous up to the boundary holomorphic function on the unit disc that can't be extended across any boundary point, and let $f(z) = g(z)+g(r/z)$. Then $f$ can't be extended across any boundary point of $r<|z|<1$.

Comment: One thing interesting to note is that in several variables, extension phenomena are plentiful. Complex analysis is really weird.

Comment: Yes, in several variables the situation is completely different.

Comment: @mrf I don't get why $1/z$ is an example: it's holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, therefore its restriction to $A(r,R)$ for any $0<r<R<+\infty$ is a bounded holomorphic function on the annulus with continuous extension to the boundary and even holomorphic extension beyond the boundary. Am I wrong? Of course there is no extension for $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-z_0}$ for some point $z_0$ on the boundary, but this is an unbounded function in the interior.

Comment: @Lor It's an example to one of the additional questions before you edited: "someting better". The second paragraph still holds after your edit though.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you explain what do $H^\infty$ and $A$ stand for?

Comment: The algebras of bounded resp. continuous up to the boundary holomorphic functions.

Comment: Great. Any reference for this result?

Comment: @Lor there's more details for you.